# 128-bit SSE counter?

Tags: optimization, sse, intrinsics, avx

I need a function of an __m128i variable that has period 2^128. It doesn't need to monotonically increase (like a counter), but visit each value once.

The simplest example I could think of is in fact a 128-bit counter, but I found that difficult to implement in SSE. Are there any simpler/faster solutions?

Comment: Why do you need to visit 2^128 values? No computer on earth is capable of doing that. Can't you use a 64-bit int?

Comment: Agree, on a processor with a clock speed on the order of gigahertz, you can consume one number every cycle for roughly 584 years before a 64-bit counter is exhausted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a monotonic counter. I'm not sure if you can call it simple though.

Assuming both `ONE` and `ZERO` are always in registers, then this should compile to 5 instructions. (7 or 8 if VEX-encoding is not used)

```
inline __m128i nextc(__m128i x){
    const __m128i ONE = _mm_setr_epi32(1,0,0,0);
    const __m128i ZERO = _mm_setzero_si128();

    x = _mm_add_epi64(x,ONE);
    __m128i t = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(x,ZERO);
    t = _mm_and_si128(t,ONE);
    t = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(ZERO,t);
    x = _mm_add_epi64(x,t);

    return x;
}
```

Test Code (MSVC):

```
int main() {

    __m128i x = _mm_setr_epi32(0xfffffffa,0xffffffff,1,0);

    int c = 0;
    while (c++ < 10){
        cout << x.m128i_u64[0] << "  " << x.m128i_u64[1] << endl;
        x = nextc(x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551610  1
18446744073709551611  1
18446744073709551612  1
18446744073709551613  1
18446744073709551614  1
18446744073709551615  1
0  2
1  2
2  2
3  2
```

---

Slightly better version suggested by @Norbert P. It saves 1 instruction over my original solution.

```
inline __m128i nextc(__m128i x){
    const __m128i ONE = _mm_setr_epi32(1,0,0,0);
    const __m128i ZERO = _mm_setzero_si128();

    x = _mm_add_epi64(x,ONE);
    __m128i t = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(x,ZERO);
    t = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(ZERO,t);
    x = _mm_sub_epi64(x,t);

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is much cleaner than mine was. I'll wait a bit to see if there're solutions other than counters.

Comment: The question is, if this is really faster than the solution not using any SSE. I mean the obvious solution using a struct of 2 64bit unsigneds and 1 branch would avoid the possible SSE overhead and the branches would be extremely predictable.

Comment: @Voo It would probably depend on what form the value is needed in. If it's needed in general registers or in memory, then a `add + adc` would be fastest. If it's needed in an SSE register, then 5 SSE-Int instructions will likely be faster than any sort of extract/insert. Passing it through memory via a struct/union will likely stall the load/store buffers since you're accessing the same memory with a different word-size.

Comment: You do have a point on branching though. It rarely ever carries over to the upper word. You could try doing something with `_mm_testz_si128` and branching on a carry. But you'd first have to mask out the upper 64-bits, so it might be just as expensive as before.

Comment: I have the feeling that the `and` instruction is unnecessary because the result of the `cmpeq` instruction is `-1` (all bits set) if the comparison is true. Just remove `t = _mm_and_si128(t,ONE);` and replace `x = _mm_add_epi64(x,t);` with `x = _mm_sub_epi64(x,t);`. Please disregard if I'm wrong.

Comment: Wow, you are right! I didn't think about that at all!!! Yes, I see no reason why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Never forget the KISS principle.

Pasting this (unsigned integers are required to wrap around by the C standard, hence visiting each value only once):

```
__uint128_t inc(__uint128_t x) {
  return x+1;
}
```

into [this](http://llvm.org/demo) yields (for x64):

```
    addq    $1, %rdi
    adcq    $0, %rsi
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movq    %rsi, %rdx
    ret
```

easy/fast enough? If you inline that, you'll probably be able to get away with just the `addq`/`adcq` (the `movq`s and `ret` are required by the x64 ABI: if you inline the function, they are not required)

---

To address Voo's comment about the suckiness of MSVC, you can use the following:

```
inline void inc(unsigned long long *x, unsigned long long *y) {
  if (!++*x) ++*y; // yay for obfuscation!
}
```

I don't have a MSVC install nearby so I can't test it, but it *should* yield something similar to what I posted above. Then, if you *really* need a __m128i, you should be able to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/site/dk2sdw0h) the two halves.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the loading from and storing into SSE registers will take a lot of time.

Comment: Depends vastly on the compiler if that code is valid or not. Pretty sure it isn't under MSVC - __m128 is just a struct of an union of smaller primitives.

Comment: @Voo see my updated answer. BTW, why are you looking for a SSE solution in the first place?

Comment: It's used in other parts of the SSE code (keying a few calculations.) But apart from being non-SSE, your solution is great!